# How to force CreatedAtRoute generate location started from https?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I do POST to my api

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' 
--header 'Accept: application/json' 
--header 'Authorization: Bearer some_token' -d '{ some_data }'
'https://here_is_url'
```

In response I get

```
{ ... "location": "http://here_is_right_url_except_http", "status": "201", ... }
```

But url in location header should be with https.

Incoming request hits balancer which is https, then requested goes as http.

Answer (score 1):

Found two ways to solve this issue.

1) Override UrlHelper

```
public class HttpsUrlHelper : UrlHelper {
         public HttpsUrlHelper(ActionContext actionContext)
    : base(actionContext) {
}

protected override string GenerateUrl(string protocol, string host, VirtualPathData pathData, string fragment) {
        return base.GenerateUrl("https", host, pathData, fragment);
    }
}

public class ForcedHttpsUrlHelperFactory : IUrlHelperFactory {
    public IUrlHelper GetUrlHelper(ActionContext context) {
        return new HttpsUrlHelper(context);
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs need to register it

```
services.AddSingleton<IUrlHelperFactory, ForcedHttpsUrlHelperFactory>();
```

2) Create new class for action Result. Also you will need to implement own CreatedAtRoute function which will return instance of HttpsCreatedAtRouteResult.

```
public class HttpsCreatedAtRouteResult : CreatedAtRouteResult {
    public HttpsCreatedAtRouteResult(object routeValues, object value)
        : base(routeValues, value) {
    }

    public HttpsCreatedAtRouteResult(string routeName, object routeValues, object value)
        : base(routeName, routeValues, value) {
    }

    public override void OnFormatting(ActionContext context) {
        base.OnFormatting(context);
        var url = context.HttpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location];

        // do with url whatever you need

        context.HttpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = url;
    }
}
```