# ASP.NET Core - CreatedAtRoute() - how to return relative location header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

In an ASP.NET core 6 ApiController I'm using `CreatedAtRoute()` as a result of a POST API:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(CatalogItem), (int)HttpStatusCode.Created)]
public async Task<ActionResult<CatalogItem>> CreateNewCatalogItemAsync(CatalogItemDto itemDto)
{
  // ...
  return CreatedAtRoute(nameof(GetCatalogItemByIdAsync), new { itemId = item.Id }, item);
}
```

This results in a location header with the absolute URL.

So my question is: How can I change this to return a relative URL instead in the Location response header?

So instead of `Location: http://foo.bar/api/item/1` I'd like to get `Location: /api/item/1`

Comment: Is this just to get shorter URLs, or for some other reason? Either way, I expect you'll need your own implementation of [`CreatedAtRouteResult`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/CreatedAtRouteResult.cs).

Comment: the API is running behind (multiple) reverse proxies. So I need to rewrite the location header if it is an absolute URL. That's a hassle I would like to get rid of

Comment: Since `CreatedAtRouteResult` uses the `IUrlHelper`, perhaps [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57518305/3181933) would also work.

Comment: Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43321034/how-to-force-createdatroute-generate-location-started-from-https) is helpful. They implement a custom `CreatedAtRouteResult` and they manipulate the value for the `Location` header

Comment: Hmm, all of these look quite heavy weight :/ I might just do some response header manipulation then if there is no easier, built-in solution http://danpatrascu.com/manipulating-response-headers-in-asp-net-core/

Comment: thanks for your comments TasosK. and DiplomacyNotWar I build a solution as shown in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments there does not seem to be any easy, built-in solution. Hence I build the following middleware, based on [this post](http://danpatrascu.com/manipulating-response-headers-in-asp-net-core/):

```cs
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(o =>
    {
        if (o is HttpContext ctx)
        {
            // In order to get relative location headers (without the host part), we modify any location header here
            // This is to simplify the reverse-proxy setup in front of the application
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Response.Headers.Location))
                {
                    var locationUrl = new Uri(context.Response.Headers.Location);
                    context.Response.Headers.Location = locationUrl.PathAndQuery;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, context);
    await next();
});
```